# One-to-Many relationship between multiple tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make a relationship between **Product** and **Brand** models with an intermediate model **BrandProduct**, intermediate model also contains some additional info like **product_model** etc.

My aim is to access all the products that belong to a specific brand with additional manufacturer info and also I want to access the brand of a specific product with additional info.

I've a `Model` named **Product** with these attributes

- id
- name
- sku
- quantity
- etc.....

Another `Model` named **Brand** with following attributes

- id
- name
- logo

And an intermediate `Model` named **BrandProduct** with attributes

- id
- brand_id
- product_id
- model
- etc.....

I'm registering Brands and Products separately and making a relationship between them by **BrandProduct** Model with additional attributes like **product_model**.

`Brand.php` model contains:

```php
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\BrandProduct');
}
```

`Product.php` model contains:

```php
public function manufacturer(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\BrandProduct');
}
```

And `BrandProduct.php` model contains:

```php
public function data(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product', 'product_id', 'id');
}

public function brand(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Brand', 'brand_id', 'id');
}
```

Now I can successfully retrieve `Product > Manufacturer` by

```php
$p = Product::find(id)->manufacturer
```

But I can't get inverse relation `BrandProduct > Data` by trying

```php
$p = BrandProduct::find(id)->data
```

Similarly I can retrieve all the `Brand > Products` by

```php
$p = Brand::find(id)->products
```

But can't get inverse relation

```php
$b = BrandProduct::find(id)->brand
```

In the end I'd like to achieve something like this:

```php
//For Brand > Products
$p = Brand::find(id)->products;

$product_model = $p[0]->model;
$product_name = $p[0]->data->name;

//For Product > Manufacturer
$p = Product::find(id)->manufacturer;
$product_model = $p->model;
$brand_name = $p->brand->name;
```

Please tell me what's wrong with my approach all other relationships are working fine except this one.

Comment: Does one `Brand` can have many `Product` and does one `Product` can be related to many Brand?

Comment: Yes a `Brand` can have multiple `Product` but one `Product` can be related to only one `Brand`

Comment: Is your scenario is like, `Brand` **Apple** has `n` number of `products`[eg. Television, Mobile Phone, Computer, etc.] .And your `Product` **Mobile Phone** has no of  `brands`[eg. Apple, Sony, Samsung, etc.]. And your intermediate model `BrandProduct` is like models(eg: Macintosh, Samsung Galaxy S8, Sony Bravia)??